# keyboard problem

Tags: hardware

When I first plugged in my raspberry pi 4 it came with a german keyboard, not an English one. I have got the English one now, but whenever I type with it, the letter E randomly gets put into the word and sometimes the computer even spams E. I have tried resetting the keyboard but that makes no difference.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. What do you mean by "resetting the keyboard"? Where did you get that keyboard from? This sounds to me like it is damaged.

Comment: what troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: Do you have this problem just on the Raspberry Pi board?